# Add-Migration error: Startup project 'MyProject' has an active platform of ''

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

When I run the commands "Add-Migration" or "Update-Database" with the package manager console in Visual Studio 2017 (Enterprise) I get this error:

> Startup project 'MyProject' has an active platform of ''. Select a different platform and try again.

I tried running as admin and reinstalling packages.

My project is an ASP.NET project.

Comment: Any news about that issue?

Comment: @gius I wish I knew how but I really have no idea how it suddenly just worked one day.

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on solution root.
- Go to properties.
- Under 'Startup Project' Select 'Single startup project' and pick one of your projects.
- Rebuild the solution.
- Run Add-Migration again.